Intensity wavelength graph random peaks

what do those peaks represent? This being in a situation where my electrons are accelerated and photons being emitted due to deceleration.

See characteristic x-rays.

Since I do not know what exactly you are doing I can not be sure. But from what you described I would assume the following is happening: You have a device producing free electrons, you accelerate them and shoot them on a target anode, where they get absorbed and emit bremsstrahlung, what is what you called photon emission by deceleration. This produces the continuous parts of your spectrum without the peaks. Now what's happening additionally is that your accelerated electrons colliding with the material will excite electrons in the material. After the excitation, the produced hole will be filled by another higher energy electron. This process will produce photons with the energy of the specific transition. Therefore this process leads to the sharply peaked intensity at the wavelengths of the these transitions.
If you can identify which transitions are causing which peaks you can then use those to calibrate your spectrum by comparing the literature on the line spectrum of the anode material to the spectrum produced by what, since you used the tag medical physics, might perhaps be some kind of Röntgen device you are using.

Your image sketches a typical X-ray spectrum.

(image from schoolphysics - X-ray spectra)
The peaks are the so-called characteristic X-ray radiation.
They got this name because they are characteristic for
the metal the anode of X-ray tube is made of.
For example: If the anode is made of copper,
then its $K_\alpha$ peak is always at wavelength
$\lambda=1.5406\ \mathring{\mathrm A}$
(corresponding to a photon energy of $8.0478$ keV).
The characteristic peaks in the X-Ray spectrum correspond to
the energy differences in the metal atoms of the anode material.
When in the X-ray tube the high energy electrons hit the anode metal,
they kick out an electron from the innermost shell (the $K$ shell)
of the metal atom.
Then an electron from a higher shell (for example the $L$ shell)
falls down into the free place in the $K$ shell, thereby emitting
the energy difference as a photon (in this example a $K_\alpha$ photon).

(image from Wikipedia - Characteristic X-ray)

that makes sense thankyou.
